# What's the purpose of function poll() in file_operations in Linux source code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I do not quite understand what will poll() do even after I tried to search for it on Google. Is there any documentation related to this function or all the interfaces in the file_operations?

Comment: You need to be more specific and show some reference to code at least. Generally `poll()` as Linux kernel interface is function that given set of file descriptors waits and blocks until one of them becomes ready to do I/O. It is well documented in [Linux Programmer's Manual manpage `poll.2`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Comment: @blami    thanks. actually, i mean the poll() interface in struct file_operations in VFS, not the one related to IO multiplexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`poll()` method in VFS struct `file_operations` is (quoting [kernel vfs documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt)):

> called by the VFS when a process wants to check if there is activity on this file and (optionally) go to sleep until there is activity. Called by the select(2) and poll(2) system calls

Note that struct contains a pointer to function of signature `__poll_t (*poll) (struct file *, struct poll_table_struct *);`. If I remember correctly, this (and most of other) `file_operations` methods are located (and pointers populated) partially by specific filesystem itself (usually in its `file.c` or similar) or - by filesystem calling out to VFS and VFS populating them by specific code for underlying block/character device.